# How much IP do you get for winning & losing games in the various modes/maps?

Tags: league-of-legends

My understanding is that you get a base number of Influence Points (IP) for losing each game and a little more for winning a game. In addition, the amount of time a games goes on seems to factor into the calculation as well. **For the following modes, what is the base IP gain for wins and losses of the various game lengths?** If there's a predictable calculation for IP per minute for wins/losses, that would be an acceptable answer.

I'm not interested in calculations including IP bonuses for your first game, bonuses for streaks of games where you didn't leave, or any other bonuses.

- PvP

  - Twisted Treeline (3v3)
  - Summoner's Rift (5v5)
- Co-op vs. AI

  - Beginner, Summoner's Rift (5v5)
  - Intermediate, Summoner's Rift (5v5)
- Custom

  - Twisted Treeline (3v3)
  - Summoner's Rift (5v5)

Bonus points if you take the initiative to calculate the optimal game length for IP gain. By that, I mean "at what point does ending the current game one way or the other and being able to start a new game result in more IP gain over the course of a play session than if the current game continued".

Comment: I think the only difference between Summoner's Rift, Twisted Treeline, and Custom games is a % multiplier.

Comment: I know for a fact I get less from AI games now that I'm 30 than I did when I was level 29 and lower.  I also believe it scales down as your level gets higher, but the jump from 29 to 30 is significant.

Comment: I get in the 8-10 range now whereas before I got in the 15-18 range, and I can remember at the beginning getting upwards of 25.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### General

- **Custom games** are only worth 75% of the IP you would have earned in a normal game.
- **Co-op vs. AI games** incur penalties based on summoner level and difficulty:

  - Level 10-19: Beginner games are worth 85%.
  - Level 20-29

    - Beginner games are worth 70%.
    - Intermediate games are worth 90%.
  - Level 30

    - Beginner games are worth 55%.
    - Intermediate games are worth 80%.

### Win

- 2.305 IP per minute up until 55 minutes.
- 18 IP bonus for completing a match (~7.8 minutes worth of IP)

### Loss

- 1.402 IP per minute up until 55 minutes.
- 16 IP bonus for completing a match (~11.4 minutes worth of IP)

### Graph

[image: IP Gain Graph]

### Optimum Game Length

Riot Games has designed their IP system to reward playing the game to completion and to reward longer games:

> Q: Will I be getting more or less IP and XP as a result of this change?
>
> A: While you will get more or less in some games, the average XP/IP gain will be much more consistent. If you typically played very long games, you will tend to get more IP and XP; however, if you typically play short games, you will get slightly less IP and XP.

While you do get a bonus beyond the "per minute IP", that bonus is designed to compensate players for the time between matches:

> Q: It seems unfair that I spend 5 minutes milling around in queue and in champion select, and don't get an IP/XP reward for that. Does this system help with this at all?
>
> A: Actually, it does! All game types give a slight 'completion bonus' that is equivalent to several minutes of play. This is embedded in IP you earn.

That being said: provided you could get into another game in substantially less that 7.8 minutes, you'd make out slightly better by surrendering and starting a new game. You'd have to do this a lot to see a substantial gain, however. If it took you longer to get into the next game, you'd actually incur a loss overall.

In short, it'll usually be best to play to 55 minutes, then bail out if you're very likely to lose. At that point, you're essentially playing to see if you'll get 145 IP vs 94 IP. If losing seems like a foregone conclusion, then you're mostly playing for the experience at that point.

### Sources

- Items in the general section: [League of Legends @ Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Influence_Points)
- Win/Loss Accrual Rates: Based on recorded values after the completion of games. There are some instances where (rate * minutes) does not exactly equal what I recorded from the game client when you round up, but overall the above rates serve as a good enough rule of thumb for my purposes.
- [IP System FAQs](http://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20008106-ip-system)

### Reference

- [League of Legends Release Notes v1.0.0.111](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=516526)
- [League of Legends Release Notes v1.53](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/ziggs-patch-notes)

Comment: And I believe the minimum game time is actually 20 minutes, not 25 minutes for Summoner's Rift and 15 minutes for Twisted Treeline.

Comment: Not only that, I'm pretty sure some of your information is just plain outdated. For instance, 55 minutes isn't the cap anymore, and I think the base values for "win" and "loss" might be off also.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right. Verified on  [LoL's support site](http://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20008106-ip-system).

Comment: From the FAQ: "All game types give a slight 'completion bonus' that is equivalent to several minutes of play. This is embedded in IP you earn."

Comment: @Raven: Actually, the limit is still 55 minutes.

Comment: I thought they confirmed there was now a bonus for longer games in one of the last few patches.

Comment: @Rapida The bonus for longer games is that you get more IP as the game goes along, up to a 55-minute game. The idea is that they want to reward people for not surrendering early. Beyond the per-minute IP gain, there's no IP bonus for simply playing a long game.

Comment: Is the IP bonus the same for Dominion versus Classic?

Comment: @Grace Note: The short answer is "no, but I don't have exact figures". I started recoding win/loss data last night. Once I've played enough games to have a good idea. I'll post the results.

Comment: @Shaun As per the [Rise of the Bot Army update](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/ziggs-patch-notes), some of these values have now been changed.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I'll look into that and update my post!

Comment: @Shaun if you update this post, please drop any "old system" data, it's totally irrelevant and confusing.

Comment: @NickT Those charts are still valid. The IP changes this round were only regarding how much of a penalty you get for bot games.