# Is it possible to gain summoner XP while afk?

Tags: league-of-legends

My summoner is still on a low level (10 currently) and I want to reach Level 20 as fast as possible to be able to buy tier 3 runes.
I wonder if it would work to create a custom game with only bots and gain experience for my summoner while I'm away from keyboard.
Other things I have in mind: Would it have any bad influence on my ELO or win-lose-statistics for normal games?

Comment: Might be worth reading up on the Leaver Buster: http://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20030633-leaver-buster-faq

Comment: It says: "This message will appear every time you leave a game but only matchmade games will be taken into account." So I'm still not sure if I had a problem this way!?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Idling in customs is probably not going to work, as your bot team will be 4v5. If the teams aren't even (say you have the enemy team 4 bots instead of 5, but your team still has 4, then you would get no experience).

Idling in games with normal people isn't cool, you will get reported and banned for wasting their time.

The only option I can think of is if you have a friend who can play the customs whilst you are afk. Even then you will have to move the mouse so you don't get kicked out of the games, and obviously you have to be present when joining games.

I really wouldn't rush getting a higher summoner level. You will be at a disadvantage to other level 20's who have played their games legit and will have a lot more experience than you. Runes also take a LOT of IP to save up for. You won't have a full rune set by the time you reach level 20, unless you use some IP boosters.

Games are meant to be fun, play with people the same level as you and enjoy yourself, don't worry about tier 3 runes yet.

---

Edit:

Ok so I didn't really consider the loss thing. If you are really hellbent on doing this then I will break it down for you.

Here is an excellent answer on IP/EXP gains per match: [How much IP do you get for winning & losing games in the various modes/maps?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/how-much-ip-do-you-get-for-winning-losing-games-in-the-various-modes-maps)

Custom games give 75% of max IP, losing gives around 70 IP per average game loss (40 mins), so thats about **52.5 IP per match**.

This works out at **120 games** (4800 minutes, or 80 hours) to get **6300 IP** using this method.

The average PC has about a 400 watt PSU. For a gaming rig I'd say *at least* 600 watt. For the time your computer is on during these games, you have used about 48 kilowatts (600 watts * 80 hours). In the UK the average price of a kilowat is about £0.11. This works out to around **£5.28 in electricity costs**.

A 6300 IP champion costs 975 RP. You can buy 839 RP for £4.50. This means **975 RP comes to around £5.17**.

**It is actually cheaper to buy RP** (although this doesn't buy you runes...)

Comment: I played some customs: me+4bots vs. 5 bots and got XP & IP even when I lost. Wont that work when afk-ing? Maybe later too at Lvl30 got get IP for runes&champs..

Comment: @F.S Edited the answer.

Comment: I did not think of running my laptop (on what I'm playing) for additional hours, more like run LoL minimized while I got other stuff to do - like contributing here ;)

Comment: Haha ;) Well you are looking at about 80 hours of idling to get to 6.3k IP.

Comment: I'd like to add that you stop getting IP for Custom games after a cap.  I believe it's 10 custom games per day.  After that, you can keep playing customs, but you'll get 0 IP.