# How is the IP reward calculated?

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know what factors determine how much IP is rewarded at the end of a round for each game type. I'm a newbie to LoL (clearly) and would like to know.

Comment: Winning, Gametype (Matchmade or Custom), Game Mode, and Game Duration all play a part. Riot has never released a formula, since they fear players would try to game the system to maximize IP gain.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm not doing this to try and maximize my IP gain. I just want to have a rough idea of how much I'll be making.

Comment: Didn't say you were. But that's why there's no official IP calculation available.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ok. I only said that because you said "since they fear players would try to game the system to maximize IP gain". Thanks for your input either way.

Comment: @RavenDreamer i would suggest you make this an answer

Comment: Is http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/how-much-ip-do-you-get-for-winning-losing-games-in-the-various-modes-maps related?

Comment: @badp It is, it awnsers the question and more.

Comment: Well, then... :)